# Duplicate product items being listed in Spree customized site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, spree

I am a pretty novice programmer and I'm working on building a web store by customizing Spree a little bit. I am trying to have a home page that shows only a few products that are designated as "featured" on the home page (based on a Taxon that a site administrator can set). However, the issue that I'm finding is that every product designated as "featured" shows up twice on my site - I have no idea why this is happening.

Here is my index.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <% if @featured_products.any? %>
    <div id="featured-products" class="row">
      <h3><center>Featured Products</center></h3>
      <hr>
      <ul class="carousel">
        <% @featured_products.each do |product| %>
          <%= render 'product', :product => product %>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Here is the products partial:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<li class="columns four" data-hook="featured_products_list_item">
<div class="product-image">
  <%= link_to product_image(product), product%>
</div>
<%= link_to truncate(product.name, :length => 50), product, :class => 'product-name', :title => product.name %>

<span><%= product.display_price %></span>
</li>
</div>
```

Here is my home controller:

```
module Spree
  class HomeController < Spree::StoreController
    helper 'spree/products'
    respond_to :html



    def index
      @searcher = build_searcher(params)
      @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
      @taxonomies = Spree::Taxonomy.includes(root: :children)


      #Addition from Spree Fancy
      featured = Spree::Taxon.where(:name => 'Featured').first
        @featured_products = featured.products.active if featured
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my products controller:

```
module Spree
  class ProductsController < Spree::StoreController
    before_filter :load_product, :only => :show
    before_filter :load_taxon, :only => :index

    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_404
    helper 'spree/taxons'

    respond_to :html

    def index
      @searcher = build_searcher(params)
      @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
      @taxonomies = Spree::Taxonomy.includes(root: :children)
    end

    def show
      return unless @product

      @variants = @product.variants_including_master.active(current_currency).includes([:option_values, :images])
      @product_properties = @product.product_properties.includes(:property)
      @taxon = Spree::Taxon.find(params[:taxon_id]) if params[:taxon_id]
    end

    private
      def accurate_title
        @product ? @product.name : super
      end

      def load_product
        if try_spree_current_user.try(:has_spree_role?, "admin")
          @products = Product.with_deleted
        else
          @products = Product.active(current_currency)
        end
        @product = @products.friendly.find(params[:id])
      end

      def load_taxon
        @taxon = Spree::Taxon.find(params[:taxon]) if params[:taxon].present?
      end
  end
end
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?! I copied a bit of code used in Spree Fancy to build this "featured products" section; however, mine seems to be listing each item twice.

Thanks everyone/anyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also noticed this happening but am not sure of the root cause, anyways here is the fix I came up with.
https://github.com/spree/spree_fancy/pull/119